# All directories are 0755, did I do something wrong?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, default

I'm new to *nix and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I've just noticed that all my directories have permissions set to 0755. That seems unsafe to me. Why do I need to grant execute perms for the world on my /usr dir?

Is this the default, or did I accidentally set this when I was granting permissions on my /srv directory.

I ran the following commands that I think may be the culprit(s):

`sudo chmod /srv/www -R 0755`

`sudo chmod g+s /srv/www`

What are the default permissions for any given Ubuntu directory?
What permissions should I set for my /srv/www webfoot directory?

**Edit:**

My /srv/www convention is like so:

`/srv/www/somedomain.com/public_html`

`/srv/www/otherdomain.com/public_html`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need execute on dirs in order to change to them. That's default and there's nothing unsafe about it. It's not "the world", though. It's just you and other users on your system.

Comment: Ah. Thanks @Jo-Erland. It really threw me because in Transmit when I viewed the 'Get Info' it reads Owner r-w-x, Group r-x, World r-x. Good to know that I haven't imploded my new server on the first day.

Comment: I don't know what Transmit is, but that description is wrong. It's User, Group and Others. (u,g,o). In this case, it means the "root" user, the "root" group or anyone in your system who isn't root, which should always be everyone, except when you explicitly want to be root (Super-Admin) :)